# How to simlify php code by using arrays from url strings

Tags: php, arrays, simplify

i'm new at this forum and php.
I want to show some info when the script detects one or more words in the postname (Wordpress)
In my exapmle like to dispaly extra info when Omnik + reset or wifi is detected.

I like to know how i can simplify the following code:

```
    $url = "www.myurl.nl/postname"
    if (strpos($url, 'omnik' )!==false){
    echo "Omnik";
    }
    else if (strpos($url, 'reset' )!==false){
    echo "Reset"; 
    }
    else if (strpos($url, 'wifi' )!==false){
    echo "Wifi";
    }
    else {
    echo "No Omnik,Reset or Wifi there";
    }
```

At this moment i can only show the extra info when the word "Omnik" is detected.
Example: https://geaskb.nl/omnik shows the extra info, but https://geaskb.nl/omnik-reset and https://geaskb.nl/omnik-wifi should show the info too, while https://geaskb.nl/solaredge shouldn't show the info.

Hope you get what i mean.

====== Added 20:00 ========

```
Hi All, thanks for the ansewers.
I should have be clear the 1st time i guess.

This is the code i use now:
```

```
    // Verkrijg URL incl. subdir.
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') 
    $geturl= "https"; 
    else
    $geturl = "http"; 
  
    // Here append the common URL characters. 
    $geturl .= "://"; 
  
    // Append the host(domain name, ip) to the URL. 
    $geturl .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
  
    // Append the requested resource location to the URL 
    $geturl .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 


    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "omnik" )!==false){
    echo "Omnik in url";
    }
    else {

    echo "Geen Omnik in $geturl";

    }
```

```
 ============= 20:30u ==================
Problem solved!! stripos solved the problem!
Thanks for all your help!
```

Comment: You could use a loop

Comment: I see you solved your problem, could you post your solution as an answer? Or if it's below can you accept the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

One way for doing it through foreach loop

```
    <?php

$url = "www.myurl.nl/postname";

$needles =  ['omnik', 'reset', 'wifi']; // Add more if needed

foreach($needles as $needle){
    if (strpos($url, $needle )!==false){
        echo $needle; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Except `ucwords` should be used on the echo. Also your solution doesn't handle the final `else`.

Comment: Yes, that depends on how you want to print it.

Comment: Noble attempt, im just not a fan of handing source code to OP's without their own demonstrated effort

Comment: On the subject of case-sensitivity, consider using stripos rather than strpos if you need to match upper- and lower-case combinations of characters in the URL (for example, if you want to to match www.myurl.nl/Omnik as well as www.myurl.nl/omnik).

Comment: @GetSet -> i can understand what you mean, but, i'm a dutch newbee trying to learn some php, so many thanks taking the time to answer

Comment: @foxsoup -> Thanks for the advice
@mail2bapi-> just tried your code, but it didnt seem to work, thats why i posted the code as i use it now. The result can be found on my website; even if there is "omnik" in the url, it wont be recognized.

Comment: @foxsoup -> stripos seemed to solve the problem,
Many thanks to you all!!